# VRTK/Unity3D/Vive VR, Touchpad Control, Move with Touchpad press, Input sometimes not received, why?

Tags: unity-game-engine, touchpad, htc-vive, vrtk

I am trying to use the Touchpad Control of the VRTK Asset for Unity VR. 
With Touchpad Touch it seems to work fairly fine, but for a more direkt input, we would like the player to actually press down on the TouchPad and hold to walk in a certain direction and to not have players accidentally activating the touchpad by just barely touching it.

Since VRTk has a Primary Activation Button for this change, this wasn't too difficult to achieve.

But the input of both controllers is sometimes read and sometimes not. Sometimes the Player presses on the TouchPad but the Player does  not move. Other times it works just fine.

Anybody have an idea why this would happen and maybe, what I could do, to always get my input and walk when the player presses the button?

At the moment sometimes it doesn't  react to it instantly, mostly it reacts a few milliseconds later after pressing the touchpad and often it doesnt read the input at all.

Comment: I had this problem before. What i did was to change my computer to a higher spec.

Comment: make sure your system specs are up to par ,